# Spring Controller servlet redirect not happends

Tags: spring

i had created a simple Spring framework, where controller (springapp dispatcherservlet redirect to the view) but it does not redirecting to the view..

i am getting the view of index1.jsp , could not able to get the view of Redirect.htm/jsp

here is my code..

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->

<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" >

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>
      index1.jsp
    </welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

### SpringApp-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--

1. This file will be used up by the DispatcherServlet and which contains the bean definition
2. The file will be picked up by the specification in the WEB-INF/web.xml using <servlet>spring</servlet>
3. hello controller is responsible for handling the request for the particular page of the website and known 
as the page controller.
-->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

  <!-- the application context definition for the springapp DispatcherServlet -->

  <bean name="Redirect.htm" class="HelloController"/>

</beans>
```

### Redirect.jsp

```
<%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : Nov 23, 2012, 11:55:53 AM
    Author     : gopc
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Hello Controller redirect</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is redirect from the HelloController!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Redirect.hml

```
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello Controller redirect</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>This is redirect from the HelloController!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### index1.jsp

```
<%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : Nov 23, 2012, 11:55:53 AM
    Author     : gopc
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

### HelloController.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author gopc
 */
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloController implements Controller {

    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());


    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        logger.info("Returning hello view");
        System.out.println("inside controller");
        return new ModelAndView("Redirect.jsp");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First I'll answer the question why you are getting index1.jsp as view. It will show you the view of index1.jsp when you run the application, **why because you have specified index1.jsp in your welcome file list in web.xml.**
    You will not be able to get Redirect.jsp, because you did not configure a view resolver in your **SpringApp-servlet.xml**.
Add following bean to your **SpringApp-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
   <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

In prefix property you have to give the path where your Redirect.jsp file is located (I am assuming in /WEB-INF/jsp folder).
In suffix property you have to specify the extension of the view to be resolved.

*Change the statement*

```
return new ModelAndView("Redirect.jsp");
```

*to*

```
return new ModelAndView("Redirect");
```

Run your application and access your application with request `/Redirect.htm`

It should work now. Hope this helps.

Be sure to read the spring reference manual at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/view.html

Comment: You are cool, it works. after moving the  inside the WEB-INF/jsp with redirect.jsp and accessing using the http://localhost:8080/SpringApp/Redirect.htm

Comment: cool, good to know that. Don't forget to accept the answer, because it helps others also to find out the correct solution.